# Receiving parse user data in a different activity than where they're set

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using parse.com as my database. In my first activity I create ParseUser objects. In the next activity I want to be able to receive them and put their data inside of a textview.

Here are the member variables.

```
private static final String COLUMN_GENDER = "gender";
private static final String MALE = "Male";
private static final String FEMALE = "Female";
protected EditText mName;
protected RadioButton mFemaleButton;
protected RadioButton mMaleButton;
protected EditText mUsername;
```

Then when the users clicks on the button I save to the database

```
String username = mUsername.getText().toString();
String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
String name = mName.getText().toString();

username = username.trim();
password = password.trim();
email = email.trim();
name = name.trim();
String gender = mMaleButton.isChecked() ? MALE : FEMALE;

final ParseUser newUser = new ParseUser();
newUser.setUsername(username);
newUser.setPassword(password);
newUser.setEmail(email);
newUser.put("name", mName.getText().toString());
newUser.put(COLUMN_GENDER, gender);
```

Comment: You can use newUser.signUpInBackground(), and then get access to the current user using ParseUser.getCurrentUser()

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass data from one activity to other one, you need to send an Intent, that will hold the data you want, and in the next activity, you need to receive that intent, as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourNextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("username", usernameVariable);
intent.putExtra("password", passwordVariable);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in the next activity, you should receive your data like this:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
String username = intent.getStringExtra("username");
String password = intent.getStringExtra("password");
```

And of course in your manifest, you have to mention that you use that other activity unless you did.

```
<application...>

<activity 
        android:name=".YourNextActivity">       
</activity>

</application>
```

Comment: note that this solution does not necessarily guarantee the user was saved correctly in the database, as the data is being passed locally. If you want to be sure the user was saved, either ensure you get a success response back from parse, or perform a query for the user data from parse in the second activity... waiting for the success response is probably better, and fits better with this answer.